# Android Google+ authorization do not works in one phone and works fine in another

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, google-play-services

I have a real problem with Android Google+ authorization.

To authorize in Google+ I use standart procedure of getting acces token:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
```

after that, if I was not previously authorized, I catch exception

```
catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
    startActivity(userRecoverableException.getIntent());
}
```

and then I repeat token request, and it works fine.

But when the app tested by my tester, it doesn't work, **permissions dialog repeated in an endless loop**.

We use th same Google+ account for authorization, and we use even the same phones - Sony Xperia with Android 4.0.4.

Logs from tester's phone didn't help me, it doesn't contain any exceptions or unusual records.

The only difference - I work from Russia, and she works from Bulgaria.

Does anybody face with similar problems?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, in Australia, on a Motorola Defy running 2.3.7 and a Galaxy S3 running 4.1.2. The odd thing is that it isn't happening on another S3 I've tried it on...

Comment: It seems, that in new version of Google Play Services Lib this bug doesn't repeat.